# using a bash script to run an interactive program

Tags: bash, shell-script

this is day one for me for bash.  perhaps this question has already been asked, but i've tried google and have come up empty. maybe because i don't know how to articulate my question.

i have a custom/inhouse linux program that prompts the end user with a bunch of questions... and ultimately uses those questions to set up some servers.
now i want to automate this so that a bash script will call the bin file and provide static answers.  ideally i want to save the answers in a file, in the order that they are asked, and just feed it to the program.

Right now, I've been looking at sample scripts that read files.  But I can't find an example that combines using file input and supplying answers to a program.

any pointers would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1**

I've tried to do the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "This script is about to call mytestapp"
mytestapp
printf 'lab\nci1\n6cr\n197\n0\n252\n888\n4\n\nAmerica/Toronto\n
~
```

When I run this, the "mytestapp" program launchs, but it sits there at the first question, waiting for input like this:

```
dev1:~# sh /tmp/test_wrapper.sh 
This script is about to call mytestapp
Enter the 3-letter location code (e.g. usa):
```

And the printf statement in the script never kicks in.

EDIT 2

i found my mistake. 
needed to pipe the params into the app:

```
 printf 'lab\nci1\n6cr\n197\n0\n252\n888\n4\n\nAmerica/Toronto\n' | mytestapp
```

Comment: Maybe this post can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804577/have-bash-script-answer-interactive-prompts

Comment: @DouglasOhlhorst thanks for the link!  It definitely got me started with some ideas.  Although please the edit i made to my question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use your `printf` command, but it's usually easier to understand and maintain using a [here-document](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html):

```
mytestapp <<EOF
lab
i1
6cr
197
0
252
888
4

America/Toronto
EOF
```